# STDIN is only working randomly [PHP CLI]

Tags: bash, php

So [I have this script](https://github.com/ProjectCleverWeb/CLI-stuff/blob/0ad58c051c7ef6a4c6c8d3e0f6ad0d9e7729fbcb/color.php) that changes the color of the text in the console. The problem is that although it accepts a string from both STDIN and the `-s` argument, it will occasionally leave out STDIN in the result. I have only noticed this when I pipe the script to itself (see below)

```
php color.php -s Hello, -c green -S underline | php color.php -s " Bob" -c red -S bold
```

The bash script above would always show " Bob" but would only show "Hello," a few times in a series of tries, **without** changing any part of the script. As far as I can tell, whether it includes it or not is very random, there is no noticeable pattern.

So my question is, how do I prevent this?

Comment: Hm, instead of reading STDIN non-blocking (data may not be there yet), you could possily read it blocking if input is not a tty: `if(!posix_isatty(STDIN)){$input = file_get_contents('php://stdin');}`

Comment: Well I wasn't expecting to get the answer that quick. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: Aight, I'll upgrade it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading non-blocking might not have the data there yet. Another option is only to read STDIN if the input is not an interactive terminal:

```
<?php
$args = getopt('s:');
if(!posix_isatty(STDIN)){
        $stdin = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
} else {
        $stdin ='';
}
echo $stdin.' '.$args['s'];
```

Comment: Thanks again, here is the answer when applied in context: [Click me](https://github.com/ProjectCleverWeb/CLI-stuff/commit/ad4e896226113ee4ebe80aa5776336a98380ddad)